# how to remove the log of ie web driver?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, html, watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver + ruby + win7 to test same pages. and I would get these logs while I start the ie explorer by using watir-webdriver:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.32.3.0
Listening on port 5555
```

are there any methods to remove these logs? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IEDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) supports a `--silent` flag that suppresses diagnostic output when the server is started.

Unfortunately, at least to my knowledge, it is not configurable when creating a browser instance. Instead, you need to directly modify the Selenium::Webdriver::IE::Server class' `server_args` method. You can modify the `lib\selenium\webdriver\ie\server.rb` file directly, but it is probably easier to monkey patch.

To monkey patch the silent flag, add the following to your code some point after requiring watir-webdriver (ie selenium-webdriver) but before opening the browser.

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::IE::Server
    old_server_args = instance_method(:server_args)
    define_method(:server_args) do
        old_server_args.bind(self).() << "--silent"
    end       
end
```

For example, the following will no longer log any messages.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

class Selenium::WebDriver::IE::Server
    old_server_args = instance_method(:server_args)
    define_method(:server_args) do
        old_server_args.bind(self).() << "--silent"
    end       
end

b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works now! and could I ask you another question please? is there any method to remove the log of chrome web driver? I am confused by these log questions, thank you again.

Comment: Yes, chromedriver is similar. I put together a blog post - [Silencing diagnostic output when starting webdrivers](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/silencing-diagnostic-output-when-starting-webdrivers/)